# Setting up OpenAM to use OpenLDAP as DataStore

Tags: ldap, openldap, openam

I am at the moment trying to configure an OpenAM installation to use an OpenLDAP as DataStore; is it possible to do it? I have seen some tips about configuring OpenLDAP (as in [this tutorial](http://linuxrelatedjotter.blogspot.it/2012/07/openam-with-openldap-as-user-store-on.html)) but this is not possible for me because LDAP is out of my control (it's customers').

How can - If possible - configure OpenAM to use OpenLDAP as DataStore without modifying OpenLDAP installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if you can't modify the OpenLDAP schema, you are out of luck. But if you have a good reason to use this LDAP server for this purpose, talk to the admin and ask him to add the necessary schemas. If you don't have that reason, you shouldn't even try anyway.

Comment: Understood. I'll try to ask for an OpenDJ installation tu be used as Datastore. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

OpenAM does not require you to change the schema, however if you do not apply the schema changes to the directory you may not be able to use certain features of OpenAM. As long as you know which features require custom schema and you are not using those, everything should be just fine. (See the schema to have a basic feeling of what features are you missing out.)

Answer (score 0):

Install your own OpenLDAP instance, configure with whatever schema is necessary. Use the translucent overlay to merge your directory view with the customer's directory.